# # ** Fatal: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I have some problems with my VHDL file:
I want to multiply 14-Bit values. For this I just used the template provided in Quartus prime and modified it slightly.
Compiling my Code works fine, but if I try to simulate it with a .vwf file I always get the `Error (vsim-3807)`.

Here is my code:

```vhdl
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    
    entity MultiplierAndCut is
    
        port 
        ( 
            a       : in signed (13 downto 0);
            b       : in signed (13 downto 0);
            clk     : in std_logic;
            clear       : in std_logic;
            result  : out signed (27 downto 0)
        );
    
    end entity;
    
    architecture rtl of MultiplierAndCut is
    
        -- Declare I/O registers
        signal a_reg, b_reg : signed (13 downto 0);
        signal out_reg    : signed (27 downto 0);
    
    begin
    
        process (clk, clear)
        begin
            if (clear = '1') then
    
                -- Reset all register data to 0
                a_reg <= (others => '0');
                b_reg <= (others => '0');
                out_reg <= (others => '0');
    
            elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    
                -- Store input and output values in registers
                a_reg <= a;
                b_reg <= b;
                out_reg <= a_reg * b_reg;
    
            end if;
        end process;
    
        -- Output multiplication result
        result <= out_reg;
    
    end rtl;
```

For my simulation I used `a = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]` **(should represent a decimal 1 in my system)** and `b = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]` **(should represent a decimal 0.25)**
My my simulation in the .vwf file looks as followed:

[image]

Thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: I'm rusty, but I think if you change a_reg and b_reg to 28-bit it will work

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis No, two 14 bit numbers mutliplied result in a 28 bit output, as done in the OP's code.

Comment: @sellerBasti vwf may be generated from a synthesised version, and it may have converted the signed ports to std_logic_vector causing a type missmatch as discribed.

Comment: Your png shows the first rising edge of clock, where A and B are registered.   Now you need to wait for one more rising edge of clk for  result to be valid.   I was not able to see that in your simulation wave.   Going further, you did not show any of the internal signals which would be helpful for debug information.

Comment: For note, just giving us the error vsim-3807 is likely meaningless to most of us.  I doubt anyone here as error codes memorized.  It would help if you posted any message that was included with the error if present.

Comment: This is meaningless without the code containing the component. For example, is teh component using std_logic_arith.signed while the entity uses numiric_std.signed?